# Error after migrating site

Tags: views, migrations

I get this error after I have migrated my site from local to live.

> Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 718 of
>   1340 bytes in views_db_object->load_row() (line 2251 of
>   /storage/content/16/184116/.com/public_html/sites/all/modules/views/includes/view.inc)

And this results in my site not showing my views. I suspect that this could have something to do with me changing "mylocalsitedirectory" to "mylivesite" in DB before importing DB to live site and ending up having a different serialization in Views than what it expects. But how do I solve this?

Comment: Go to `admin/config/development/performance` and purge the cache. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Change the serialised string back to its original state, use `unserialize` to get the php array, change the array value you need to **in PHP**, then `serialize` it up again before pasting into the relevant db field. Simple as that :)

Comment: Or, even simpler, change the identifier preceding that value, e.g. `s:123:` to match the char count of the string after its been changed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to delete everything.  Using database viewing/querying software (phpMyAdmin, dbForge Express, etc.), you can identify exactly which view is causing problems allowing you to remove only one view or attempt to fix it.

It is detailed in this answer: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/105393/8506

Answer (score 0):

This is a painful process, but gets the job done.

- Delete the two tables views_display and views_views
- Export all views manually using Drupal export view from development
  environment
- Import all views manually using Drupal import view in production
  environment

Comment: Should I not TRUNCATE the two tables and then export data? Or do the import also create the tables?

Comment: The import should create the tables. So truncate the tables

Comment: what if i've got hundreds of views? Any other solution?(

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success with this script:

http://davidcoveney.com/782/mysql-database-search-replace-with-serialized-php/