# "Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 10301 of 11637 bytes on views_db_object->load_row()"

Tags: views

I use the E-Commerce Kickstart distribution. Almost always I get some error, every time I update and save any view.

[image: screenshot]

Please could anybody tell me what is causing this error, or give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered the same issue and thus far to resolve but I found this article.

http://www.zyxware.com/articles/3337/drupal-errors-drupal-views-notice-unserialize-function-unserialize-error-at-offset-1009-of-1036-bytes-in-views-db-

so...i researched some more and found this solution. I added this line to bootstrap.inc

```
$data = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!e', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $variable->value);  
$variables[$variable->name] = unserialize($data);
```

in the variable_init function

Answer (score 2):

I know this was answered long ago, but this is to help out future Googlers.

All unserialize errors result from bad data in the database.  Data stored in a serialized format will look like this:

```
s:9:"my string";
```

- s - datatype (in this case string)
- 9 - length of the data
- "my string" - the data

In your case, the unserialize error is resulting from a view. If you have a database viewer/query program (i.e. phpmyadmin, dbForge Express, Navicat etc.) you can look at the views tables.  You'll find that the only one containing serialized data is the views_display table; the display_options field contains serialized data.  You can then execute a query such as the following:

```
SELECT vid, display_title, length(display_options)
FROM views_display
WHERE length(display_options)="11637"
```

- vid, display_title are used to identify which record from the database is corrupted
- display_options is the **field containing serialized data**, could be stored in database as longtext or a blob
- views_display is the table we are searching as it is relevant to the error and contains serialized data
- "11637" is the length of the data stored in the field and **corresponds to the bigger number on the error**

This particular query should return one result with the view id.  You have the option to **delete the view** or try to **repair the data**.

To repair the data copy the serialized data into a text editor that will tell you what column/character you are on. In your case, you would go to column/character 10301 (the first number in the error) and see if you can identify a mismatch (wrong datatype, incorrect length, incorrect syntax). Copy the corrected data back into the database.

Comment: This is a great answer because it actually explains what is causing the problem, which clarifies why the accepted solution works.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I faced the same problem. Solutions above didn't look very reliable to run on production.. **Luckily I had a dev server where the view was working fine so I did the following**:

**Export the view:**

1. Login to my Drupal site dev server
2. Go to **/admin/structure/views** and **export the view** from there
3. Copy the exported view code

**Import the view:**

1. On the drupal site that has the view issue, goto: **/admin/structure/views/import**
2. And paste the view code there
3. Make sure to check "Replace an existing view if one exists with the same name"
4. **Click Import**
5. Do not forget to save!

The imported view code solved the issue for me and hope that works for you as well!